# DateTime ParseExtract seconds when ss is more than 59

Tags: c#, datetime

`s_Time = DateTime.ParseExact("113388", "HHmmss", null);`

Getting Error when `ss` is more than 59. How can avoid this.
 If `ss` is more than 59 i want to display it as 00.

How can i achieve this?

Actually i have a file name which contains time to validate. ss will come randomly it may be 00 to 99, how ever i have to show 00 when its grater than 59

Comment: "ss" expects a number 00 through 59 per the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#ssSpecifier if you need something else you'll have to custom parse the string. Also, shouldn't it display as 00 with an extra minute?

Comment: Could you provide more information about *why* you want to do this?  It would help if we knew whether you meant this to represent a time-of-day or an elapsed time.  But either way, it doesn't make sense to have 88 seconds in a minute.

Comment: Also, I assume you meant the first argument to be a string, not an integer?  If so, you would need quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on my comment, something this makes the most sense to me.  Treat the string as adding onto the hours and minutes that you parse.

```
var temp = "113388";
s_Time = DateTime.ParseExact(temp.Substring(0, 4
), "HHmm", null).AddSeconds(int.Parse(temp.Substring(4)));
```

I would only ever check this into production when the second hand says 88 though =)

Answer (score 0):

Hexxagonal [probably has the most sensible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26228832/336648), but if you *should* for some reason want to replace the last part of the string (the seconds) with "00" when the value is above 59, and *not* update the minutes part, then this should work:

```
var input = "113388"; // original
var secsPart = input.Substring(4);
// Get 00 if over 59, else keep the seconds as they are:
var seconds = int.Parse(secsPart) > 59 ? "00" : secsPart; 
var editedInput = input.Substring(0,4) + seconds;

var s_Time = DateTime.ParseExact(editedInput, "HHmmss", null);
```