# Any workaround to TimeSpan.ParseExact with more than 59 seconds?

Tags: c#, .net, timespan, datetime-parsing

I am developing an app that takes track of transcurred times, and the user must be able to set the app time format as he wants, for example:

```
"ss:fff" (seconds:miliseconds)
"ss\s\. fff mils\." (seconds s. miliseconds mils.)
"dd:hh:mm" (days:hours:minutes)
etc...
```

I store the times as long, so with a simple TimeSpan formatting I can show them with the user configurated format, easy and actually working.

The problem came up when I started to implement a "by-hand" time addition (the user types a new time in a TextBox and it's added to the times list with the configured time format).

Just after the user introduced a new time I have to convert the introduced time from string to long with the prupose of storing it (TimeSpan.TryParseExact providing the configured time format does the work), except for one problem: if we have a format like mm:ss and the parsed time is something as 90:32, the parse fails because the time to parse should not have > 59 minutes.

I made a small Console App example to help reproduce my issue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string TimeFormat = @"ss\:fff";

        long[] SampleTimes = new long[] { 1000, 5000, 59666 };
        List<long> times = new List<long>(SampleTimes);

        string input;
        long aux;
        do
        {
            ShowTimes(times, TimeFormat);

            Console.Write(">");
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (TryParseTime(input, TimeFormat, out aux))
                times.Add(aux);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Failed parsing");

        } while (input != "Exit");
    }

    static void ShowTimes(IEnumerable<long> times, string format)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----");
        foreach (long time in times)
            Console.WriteLine(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time).ToString(format));
        Console.WriteLine("-----");
    }

    static bool TryParseTime(string time, string format, out long parsed)
    {
        TimeSpan result;
        bool ok = TimeSpan.TryParseExact(time, format, null, out result);
        parsed = ok ? (long)result.TotalMilliseconds : -1;
        return ok;
    }
```

In another posts [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228694/datetime-parseextract-seconds-when-ss-is-more-than-59), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751325/parse-a-timespan-greater-than-24-hours)] referencing the same issue they worked around it separating the parts of the introduced time and calculating it from code:

```
//From first post
var temp = "113388";
s_Time = DateTime.ParseExact(temp.Substring(0, 4
), "HHmm", null).AddSeconds(int.Parse(temp.Substring(4)));

//From second post
public static decimal Hours(string s)
{
    decimal r;
    if (decimal.TryParse(s, out r))
        return r;

    var parts = s.Split(':');
    return (decimal)new TimeSpan(int.Parse(parts[0]), int.Parse(parts[1]),0).TotalHours;
}
```

But I cannot folow this way because there is not a time format to take as reference to split the introduced one, it can change at any moment.

The only idea I got at this moment is to create a TimeSpan.TryParseExact expansion method that takes the biggest time unit by regex and parses it by separate...

Any better way to do that?

Comment: Yep, if you’re going to allow them to put in their own format for dates then you’re going to have to use it to tokenize their data entry.. hopefully putting some tracking in of how many users actually change the format away from hh:mm:ss will give some insight as to whether you should bother or whether it should just be a choice of a couple of formats. My guess is most users will keep the default

Comment: It looks like checks for max 59 for minutes and seconds is hardcoded in TimeSpanParse utility class, so you have to create your own parser to allow minutes greater than 59. You can actually fetch TimeSpanParse.cs reference source, copy to your own project, rename it and carefully patch - so it will support all that original supports, but will be able to use out-of-range values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I ended up with this custom method to do the work.

It's not a method to execute many times in a row because of the huge performance issues it will have, but to parse the introduced data from the front end it's more than acceptable:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Given a time and a format it creates a <see cref="TimeSpan"/> ignoring the format digit limitations.
    /// The format is not validated, so better ensure a correct one is provided ;)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="time"></param>
    /// <param name="format"></param>
    /// <param name="timeSpan"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool TryParseTime(string time, string format, out TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        // Regex to match the components of the time format (ss:fff matches ss and fff)
        var formatRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*)(%?([fFsmhd])(\2*))");
        var matches = formatRegex.Matches(format);
        if (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            // We build a big regex to extract the values from time
            string formatExtractionRegex = string.Empty;
            int pivot = 0;
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    char c = match.Value.ToLower()[0];
                    formatExtractionRegex += $@"{format.Substring(pivot, match.Index - pivot)}(?<{c}>\d+)";

                    pivot = match.Index + match.Length;
                }
            }

            var timeParts = new Regex(formatExtractionRegex).Match(time);
            int d, h, m, s, f;
            int.TryParse(timeParts.Groups["d"].ToString(), out d);
            int.TryParse(timeParts.Groups["h"].ToString(), out h);
            int.TryParse(timeParts.Groups["m"].ToString(), out m);
            int.TryParse(timeParts.Groups["s"].ToString(), out s);
            int.TryParse(timeParts.Groups["f"].ToString(), out f);
            timeSpan = new TimeSpan(d, h, m, s, f);
            return true;
        }

        timeSpan = default;
        return false;
    }
```

The method extracts the data from the time by building a big regex that replaces the digit type for the regex expression `\d+`, so we select entire digit groups when they are longer than what the format specifies.

If we provide a time `100:100:5000` and a format `mm\:ss\:fff`, the generated regex will be `(?<m>\\d+)\\:(?<s>\\d+)\\:(?<f>\\d+)`.

Finally we parse the matched groups and we parse them to be given to the [TimeSpan Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_).

Answer (score 1):

Seems reasonable to me; get your users to enter a string like:

```
T-{hour}h{min}m{sec}s [baby!]
```

And regex escape it, then string replace it (eg `"{hour}"` -> `"(?<h>\d+)"`) to become a regex:

```
T-(?<h>\d+)h(?<m>\d+)m(?<s>\d+)s \[baby!\]
```

And also string replace it to become a time span output format:

```
'T-'hh'h'mm'm'ss's [baby!]'
```

Then you have your capturing groups.. They can type their weird time format, you can parse it, you can output it..

Comment: How do you see the custom method I made?